# Angular - How to allow only one checkbox to be selected in dynamic FormArray

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular12, formarray

I have Angular-12 dynamic FormArray:

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  VERSION
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  contactInfoForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.updateContact();
  }

  get contacts() {
    return this.contactInfoForm.controls['contacts'] as FormArray;
  }

  getFormGroup(index: number): FormGroup {
    return this.contacts.at(index) as FormGroup;
  }

  updateContact() {
    this.contactInfoForm = this.fb.group({
      id: [''],
      current_residential_address: [
        '', [
          Validators.required,
          Validators.minLength(2),
          Validators.maxLength(500)
        ]
      ],
      contacts: this.fb.array([this.addContactFormGroup()])
    });
  }

  addContactFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      phone_type_id: ['', Validators.required],
      phone_number: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(15)]],
      is_primary_contact_number: ['']
    });
  }

  public addContactButtonClick() {
    const contacts = this.contactInfoForm.get('contacts') as FormArray
    contacts.push(this.addContactFormGroup())
  }

  get fc() {
    return this.contactInfoForm.controls;
  }
}
```

```
<form [formGroup]="contactInfoForm">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-12">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="current_residential_address">Current Residential Address:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <textarea rows="2" formControlName="current_residential_address" name="description" type="text" placeholder="22, Alexander Close ..." class="form-control mb-3" required>
                            </textarea>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.touched && fc.current_residential_address.invalid">
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('required')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address is required!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('minlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be less than 2 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
        <div *ngIf="fc.current_residential_address.hasError('maxlength')">
          <div class="text-danger">
            Current Residential Address cannot be more than 500 characters!
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div formArrayName="contacts" class="col-md-12" *ngFor="let contact of contacts.controls; let i = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="i" class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_number">Phone Number:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <div class="input-group mb-4">
              <input type="text" formControlName="phone_number">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number').touched && getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number').invalid">
            <div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number').hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Number is required!
              </div>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_number').hasError('validatePhoneNumber')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Invalid Phone Number!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone_type_id">Phone Type:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" formControlName="phone_type_id">

          </div>
          <div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_type_id').touched && getFormGroup(i).get('phone_type_id').invalid">
            <div *ngIf="getFormGroup(i).get('phone_type_id').hasError('required')">
              <div class="text-danger">
                Phone Type is required!
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="is_primary_contact_number">Is Primary Line?:</label><br>
            <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i> Remove</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary float-right" (click)="addContactButtonClick()" matTooltip="Add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Add item</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  {{ "Is Form Valid : "+contactInfoForm.valid}}
</form>
```

A user can only have one primary line. So in the FormArray, I want the user to be able to check only one of the checkboxes for `is_primary_contact_number` to only be selected or checked once.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For the checkbox element, add `(change)` event with `onIsPrimaryContactChecked(i)` by parsing the `FormArray` index.
2. In `onIsPrimaryContactChecked` method, iterate with `this.contacts` FormArray, skip current checkbox index, otherwise set the remaining checkboxes to `false`.

> app.component.html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck2" formControlName="is_primary_contact_number" (change)="onIsPrimaryContactChecked(i)">
```

> app.component.ts

```js
onIsPrimaryContactChecked(index: number) {
  for (let i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++) {
    if (i == index) continue;

    this.getFormGroup(i)
      .get('is_primary_contact_number')
      ?.setValue(false);
  }
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-klathu)

Comment: It highlights :        this.getContactFormGroup(i)
     object is possibly 'null'   and says

Comment: Hi, updated my answer. As [`AbstractControl.get()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) returns value of `AbstractControl` or `null` type. This change `this.getFormGroup(i).get('is_primary_contact_number')?.setValue(false);` will fix the warning.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {Component, HostListener, OnDestroy, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

import {ActivatedRoute, Params, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';


import {IQuery} from '../../../../shared/interfaces/query.interface';

import {LocationChangeListener} from "@angular/common";
import {faAsterisk} from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import {IGroupPermission} from "../group.permission.interface";
import {GroupPermissionService} from "../group.permission.service";
import {GroupPermission} from "../group.permission.model";
import {IGroup} from "../../group/group.interface";
import {IPermission} from "../../permission/permission.interface";
import {GroupService} from "../../group/group.service";
import {PermissionService} from "../../permission/permission.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-permission-group-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.scss']
})
export class EditComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  faIcon = {faAsterisk};
  formGroup!: FormGroup;
  submitted: boolean;
  editId: number;
  subscription: Subscription[];
  permissionGroupDetail!: IGroupPermission;
  groupRows!: IGroup;
  permissionRows!: IPermission;

  isGet: boolean;
  isPut: boolean;
  isPost: boolean;
  isDelete: boolean;
  isCheck: boolean;

  @HostListener('window:popstate', ['$event'])
  onPopState(event: LocationChangeListener): void {

    let params: IQuery = {};


    this.subscription.push(this.permissionGroupService.getQueryArgumentObservable().subscribe((qParams: IQuery) => {

      params = qParams;
    }));

    this.permissionGroupService.setQueryArgument(params);
    this.router.navigate(['./admin/group-permission/list'], {
      queryParams: params,

    });
  }

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
              private permissionGroupService: GroupPermissionService,
              private aRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private groupService: GroupService,
              private  permissionService: PermissionService,
  ) {
    this.submitted = false;
    this.editId = 0;

    this.isDelete = false;
    this.isGet = false;
    this.isPost = false;
    this.isPut = false;
    this.isCheck = false;
    this.subscription = [];

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({

      permissionId: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(255)
      ]),
      groupId: new FormControl('', [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.maxLength(255)
      ]),
      actions: this.formBuilder.array([], [])

    });


    this.subscription.push(this.aRoute.params.pipe().subscribe((params: Params) => {

      this.editId = +params.id;

    }));


    this.groupService.query();

    this.subscription.push(
      this.groupService.getDataObservable().subscribe((groups: IGroup) => {
        this.groupRows = groups;

      })
    );
    this.permissionService.query();
    this.subscription.push(
      this.permissionService.getDataObservable().subscribe((permision: IPermission) => {
        this.permissionRows = permision;
      })
    );
    this.permissionGroupService.query(this.editId);
    this.subscription.push(this.permissionGroupService.getDataObservable().subscribe((permission: IGroupPermission) => {
      this.permissionGroupDetail = permission;

      this.formGroup.controls.groupId.setValue(permission.data![0].groupId);
      this.formGroup.controls.permissionId.setValue(permission.data![0].permissionId);
    }));

    this.permissionGroupDetail.data![0].actions.split("-").forEach(value => {

      if (value === "get")
        this.isGet = true;
      else if (value === "post")
        this.isPost = true;

      else if (value === "put")
        this.isPut = true;

      else if (value === "delete")
        this.isDelete = true;

    });
  }

  onSubmit(): void {


    if (this.formGroup.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.submitted = true;
    const actions: FormArray = this.formGroup.get('actions') as FormArray;
    let combineAction = '';

    actions.controls.forEach(ctl => combineAction += ctl.value);

    const permissionGroup = new GroupPermission({
      id: this.editId,
      groupId: this.formGroup.value.groupId,
      permissionId: this.formGroup.value.permissionId,
      actions: combineAction,

    });

    this.permissionGroupService.clearAlert();
    this.permissionGroupService.update(permissionGroup);

  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {

    this.subscription.forEach(sub => sub.unsubscribe());
    this.permissionGroupService.unsubscribe();


  }

  onCheckboxChange(e: any) {

    const actions: FormArray = this.formGroup.get('actions') as FormArray;

    if (!this.isCheck) {
      this.isCheck = true;
      const actBox = this.permissionGroupDetail.data![0].actions.split("-");
      actBox.forEach(value => {
        if (value)
          actions.push(new FormControl("-" + value));

      });
    }
    if (e.target.checked) {

      const index = actions.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === e.target.value);
      if (index == -1)
        actions.push(new FormControl(e.target.value));
    } else {

      const index = actions.controls.findIndex(x => x.value === e.target.value);

      actions.removeAt(index);
    }


  }

}




<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" [formGroup]="formGroup">


  <div class="form-group">
    <app-alert></app-alert>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{ 'filed.group' | translate }}</div>
      <select

        id="groupId"
        name="groupId"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="groupId"
        required
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': formGroup.controls.groupId.invalid  && formGroup.controls.groupId.touched }"

      >
        <option disabled selected value>{{ 'common.selectInputMessage' | translate }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let group of this. permissionRows?.data; let i=index" value="{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}</option>

      </select>
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <fa-icon  [icon]="faIcon.faAsterisk" ></fa-icon>
      </div>

      <div
        *ngIf=" !submitted &&formGroup.controls.groupId.invalid ||formGroup.controls.groupId.touched"
        class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls.groupId.hasError('required')" class="pull-right"> {{ 'common.required' | translate }}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{ 'filed.permissionId' | translate }}</div>
      <select

        id="permissionId"
        name="permissionId"
        class="form-control"
        formControlName="permissionId"
        required
        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': formGroup.controls.permissionId.invalid  && formGroup.controls.permissionId.touched }"

      >
        <option disabled selected value>{{ 'common.selectInputMessage' | translate }}</option>
        <option *ngFor="let group of this.groupRows?.data; let i=index" value="{{group.id}}">{{group.name}}</option>

      </select>
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <fa-icon  [icon]="faIcon.faAsterisk" ></fa-icon>
      </div>

      <div
        *ngIf=" !submitted &&formGroup.controls.permissionId.invalid ||formGroup.controls.permissionId.touched"
        class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="formGroup.controls.permissionId.hasError('required')" class="pull-right"> {{ 'common.required' | translate }}
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group">
      <div class="input-group-addon">{{ 'filed.actions' | translate }}</div>

      <div class="form-control form-check-inline form-check" style="border: none">
        <!--        <label *ngFor="let act of this.actionsArray; let i = index"-->
        <!--               for="inline-checkbox1"-->
        <!--               class="switch switch-text switch-primary switch-pill m-r-10 m-l-20">-->
        <!--          <input-->
        <!--            (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)"-->
        <!--            type="checkbox"-->
        <!--            id="inline-checkbox1"-->
        <!--            value="{{act.value}}"-->
        <!--            class="form-check-input witch-input">{{ act.name}}-->

        <!--        </label>-->

        <label style="  transform: scale(1)" class="switch switch-text switch-primary switch-pill lg m-r-10 m-l-20">
          <input  value="-get" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" type="checkbox" class="switch-input " [checked]="isGet" >
          <span data-on="Get" data-off="Get" class="switch-label"></span>
          <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>



        <label style="  transform: scale(1)" class="switch switch-text switch-success switch-pill m-r-5 m-l-5">
          <input value="-post" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" type="checkbox" class="switch-input" [checked]="isPost" >
          <span data-on="Pst" data-off="Pst" class="switch-label"></span>
          <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>

        <label style="  transform: scale(1)"  class="switch switch-text switch-warning switch-pill m-r-5 m-l-5">
          <input value="-put" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" type="checkbox" class="switch-input" [checked]="isPut" >
          <span data-on="Put" data-off="Put" class="switch-label"></span>
          <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>
        <label  style="  transform: scale(1)" class="switch switch-text switch-danger switch-pill  m-l-5">
          <input value="-delete" (change)="onCheckboxChange($event)" type="checkbox" class="switch-input"  [checked]="isDelete" >
          <span style="font-size: 10px !important;" data-on="Del" data-off="Del" class="switch-label"></span>
          <span class="switch-handle"></span>
        </label>





      </div>
      <div class="input-group-addon">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faIcon.faAsterisk"></fa-icon>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="form-actions form-group ">
    <button  [disabled]="formGroup.invalid"  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">{{ 'common.submit' | translate }}</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).